# Getting the context of the template inside of which my component has been rendered

Tags: angular

Problem is simple, i have this (well... not this, but something logically similar):

```
<many-items [Items]="items">
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
        <single-item>{{item.prop1}}</single-item>
        <single-item>{{item.prop2}}</single-item>
        <single-item>{{item.prop3}}</single-item>
        <single-item>{{item.prop4}}</single-item>
        <single-item>{{item.prop5}}</single-item>
    </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

From inside `<single-item>` i want to be able to access the `item` instance, ***without*** having to pass it to each `<single-item>` component, aka, not this:

```
...
<single-item [Context]="item">{{item.prop1}}</single-item>
...
```

**With View Engine, I'm doing:**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.Context = (<any>this._viewContainer)._view.context.$implicit;
}
```

**Angular Ivy broke this (i realize `_view` is an internal so shame on me but ¯\__(ツ)_/¯) and now i'm using this:**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.Context = (<any>this._viewContainer)._hostView.debug.context.$implicit;
}
```

This is getting a bit too hacky for my eyes to bear, and doesn't even work if i'm using `enableProdMode();` so i was wondering if i had a non-hacky way to retrieve what i need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the `debug` variable in `(<any>this._viewContainer)._hostView` actually gets generated using `_hostView`'s properties [to be more readable during debug](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d528dedd5007dd7272878bf7a933cb1f3e153ed0/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/lview_debug.ts#L30)

That means that, by peeking the `_hostView` itself, which is [an array](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d528dedd5007dd7272878bf7a933cb1f3e153ed0/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/lview_debug.ts#L32) i can find what i'm looking for.

Since i'm pretty lazy and just want to be done with this at this point, i'll just find the first property of this array which contains the `$implicit` property like so:

```
(<any>this._viewContainer)._hostView.find(t => t && !!t.$implicit).$implicit
```

This will be my context and it will be retrieved both in dev and production mode. Yay.

Here hoping for a better way to do this